# Who peer-reviews suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Do peer reviews go to just anyone, or do you need a certain amount of reputation to review suggested edits?

Comment: Big thanks to Eric Carvalho who reviews tons of our edits. Eric, thank you very much for your work!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need at least 2000 reputation to review suggested edits.

Answer (score 4):

As edwinksl already pointed out, all users above 2000 reputation (sorry for stealing that I don't see the numbers anymore) can review edits.

So reviews are done by the community, or to better quote whats on the reviews page written:

> Ask Ubuntu is moderated by
>   [you](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Help your fellow members learn to use the site and raise the quality
>   of Q&A by:
>
> - Evaluating new posts
> - Voting to close or reopen questions
> - Reviewing suggested edits